# How to edit css when file is uploaded

Tags: javascript

I have a form where users can upload a file. The uploading and validation afterwards (filesize, filetype...) is done with php by submitting.

But I wonder how I could give the user a "visual feedback" that his file was "picked" immediately. So I don't need validation nor anything complex. I just want to either color the label green or rename the label of the upload field when the user has selected a file and clicked "Choose" in his browser.

How would I do that most easily?

Answer (score 0):

On success assign one variable then use that variable to add class to the element.